# Set and Get value in ViewState when page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

When my page loads it is calling `set` method followed by `get` method.  But when I click on link button in treeview, then first `get` method is called followed by `set` method. I think it is not correct as I expect the `set` method to be called before `get` method.[image][image]

Here image icon are first `set` and then `get` on pageload, but when click on link button it is postback and calls `get` method and then `set`, due to this  `ViewState["ExtensionOrFile"]` returns null in `get` when link button is clicked.

```
get
{
    string s = (string)ViewState["ExtensionOrFile"];
    if(s == null) return "";
    return s;
} 
set{ ViewState["ExtensionOrFile"] = value; }
```

when pageload it calling first `Set` and then `Get` it is correct for my page but when page post back on link button click it calling first `Get` and then `Set` it is not correct for me..becase it return null value and then `Set` value in Viewstate["ExtensionOrFile"].

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No,its not possible to change the sequence of it tell me what you want to achieve so we can give you another idea

Comment: when pageload first call `set` and then `get` but when click on link butoon of treeview it reverse.
but i want first call set and then get like on page load

Comment: ammm not like this man \

Comment: means i dont understand??

Comment: first call set and then get

Comment: so what can i do ???@ dholakiyaankit

Comment: where you are binding value to viewstate?

Comment: WHEN CALLING   set{ ViewState["ExtensionOrFile"] = value; }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48238/discussion-between-pratik-patel-and-dholakiyaankit)

Comment: but in value? what you have